# javafx checkbox handle the event on the same object that generates it

Tags: events, checkbox, javafx, listener

I have a code like this:

```
CheckBox checkboxFrame1;

    checkboxFrame1.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
            if (!chk.isSelected()) 
            {
                if (makeNotSelected()) {
                     chk.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

or another version:

```
checkboxFrame1.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if (makeNotSelected()) {
                     checkboxFrame1.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Both of these codes do not work. I think that they do not work to avoid race conditions.

How can I use an event that changes the status (selected or not) of the object - checkbox - that caused it ?

My goal is through the testing using makeNotSelected () method, put the checkbox just selected in the non-selected state.

Comment: There are no race conditions here, because everything is occurring on only one thread. The first code block cannot possibly do anything that has any effect, because the only thing you execute is `chk.setSelected(false)`, and you only do that if `chk` is already unselected. What is the logic in `makeNotSelected()`? What are you actually trying to do? What happens in the second code block?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you want to reverse the state of your checkbox when checking?

Comment: @James_D   I want to change the state of the checkbox when I select, and based on the value returned by makeNotSelected() put it in the not selected state.

Comment: @Bo Halim I want to change the state of the checkbox when I select, and based on the value returned by makeNotSelected() put it in the not selected state.

Comment: It works fine for me (though I think this is kind of weird: why wouldn't you just disable the check box instead of immediately undoing the user's action?) If it doesn't work the way you expect, you need to create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved using a code like this:

```
checkboxFrame1.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if ((makeNotSelected())&&(checkboxFrame1.isSelected())) {
                 checkboxFrame1.setDisable(true);
                 checkboxFrame1.setSelected(false);
                 checkboxFrame1.setDisable(false);
        }
    }
});
```